Object is possibly 'null'.ts-plugin(2531) in if block
I have the following code, I have checked the event.target. So I think the event.target should not nullable in if.
const importDatabase = async (event: Event) => {
  if (event.target) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0]
    const connection = getDbConnection()

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const data = new Uint8Array(e.target!.result as ArrayBuffer)
      console.info('Importing database...', data)
      // const SQL = await initSqlJs()
      // connection.driver.databaseConnection = new SQL.Database(data);
      connection.sqljsManager.loadDatabase(data)
      await connection.synchronize(false)
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  }
}



The error is not referring to event.target, it is referring to (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files. This might be null, in which case you cannot index it.
HTMLInputElement's files property documentation:

Value
A FileList object listing the selected files, if any, or null if the HTMLInputElement is not of type="file".


You are right, thanks, I got it.

The answer from @virchau13 is correct, I updated the code to the following.
const importDatabase = async (event: Event) => {
  if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) || event.target.files === null) return
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  const connection = getDbConnection()

  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = async (e) => {
    const data = new Uint8Array(e.target!.result as ArrayBuffer)
    console.info('Importing database...', data)
    // const SQL = await initSqlJs()
    // connection.driver.databaseConnection = new SQL.Database(data);
    connection.sqljsManager.loadDatabase(data)
    await connection.synchronize(false)
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
}



